# $uibModal not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

```
$scope.openModal = function() {
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      templateUrl: 'views/modals/addToCartModal.html',
      controller: 'RandomController',
      // template: '<div class="modal-header">Hi</div>'
    })
  };
}])
```

I accessing Angular Modals using angular-ui-bootstrap for the first time. It is not throwing any error but showing a simple black line. When I use template it is working fine but when I use templateUrl it showing black line. Any ideas reason behind unpredictable behaviour.

Comment: The path `views/modals/addToCartModal.html` would work for `template` attribute

Comment: Check in your network tab, is this tempate getting loaded or not ?